# DevTools is switching to the Sources tab automatically whenever a page is refreshed

Tags: debugging, microsoft-edge, devtools

Whenever I use the DevTools, if the web page is refreshed, DevTools switches to the Sources tab and opens every script.

Answer (score 10):

There's a feature called "Focus Sources panel when triggering a breakpoint" in Devtools. You can find it in devtools Settings --> Preferences --> Sources. This feature is enabled by default.[image]

So if you have any breakpoint triggered, everytime you refresh the page, the devtools will be switched to Sources panel.

Comment: Thanks for answer I tried it but this solution didn't solve my problem

Comment: I need to confirm: Do you have this issue ONLY when you switch to Sources panel and refresh the page, or you have this issue no matter which panel you switches to before you refresh the page? Like, you have the **Elements** panel on, then you refresh the page, and you still have the **Sources** panel?

Comment: it is only happening when I'm working on my company project. While program is running with Visual studio(localhost) and waiting to see a response on devops network tab, every time page reloads, it switches to source tab and screen quickly shows every background activity(scripts) as flashes for 3-4 secs. None of my colleagues has such a problem. So no one could able to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Cause of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKV7k.png)

I found cause of my problem. I activated JS debugger which is why this action occurred.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future with similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).