# How to stop Edge opening an unwanted dotnet.xxx.js Blazor file?

Tags: blazor, google-chrome-devtools, blazor-webassembly, edge-devtools

When I have the browser console <kbd>F12</kbd> open, every time I press <kbd>F5</kbd> on my Blazor Page, a `dotnet.6.0.8.xxx.js` tab opens. Even If I am on the Network View, it jumps directly to the sources view.

If I close the dotnet.6.0.8.xxx.js, it opens itself again on refresh. This applies to Edge and Chrome.

[image: DevTools]

I have no breakpoints in the browser and no breakpoints in Visual Studio:

[image: No Breakpoint claim]

It only stops opening when disabling "*Focus Sources panel when triggering a breakpoint*", but this would disable this feature in general (In case I want to look for a breakpoint).

This seems wrong to me. Do you have any hint, what could possible trigger this behavior?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in Chrome? Do you have the issue if you run other pages? I made a test with [a simple Blazor app](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/create) but I can't reproduce the issue. If you close the `dotnet.6.0.8.xxx.js` tab manually, will it show again after refreshing?

Comment: Besides, *"Even If I am on the Network View, it jumps directly to the sources view"* this behavior is very similar with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73290639/devtools-is-switching-to-the-sources-tab-automatically-whenever-a-page-is-refres), you can also check if the solutions in it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link @YuZhou . Same problem in Chrome, but when disabling *"Focus Sources panel when triggering a breakpoint"* it stops opening. Otherwise it keeps opening, even If I close it everytime. I have no breakpoints in the browser, and no breakpoints in Visual Studio. Very strange.

Comment: For my no breakpoint in browser claim, I assume it would be listed [there](https://imgur.com/wBmxhiw)? I remember I have looked through the framework files out of curiosity.

Comment: Yes, it would show there if you have breakpoints in browser. The page looks like framework file, maybe you opened it before when you check the files. But it's strange that it opens without any breakpoint. And the issue shows in both Edge and Chrome, I think it will related with breakpoints and codes. You can check again in VS to see if you have set any breakpoints accidently or if there's any code would trigger break in the code.

Comment: I get the same in Chrome.